# Is a good practice return a list of valid values in a Bad Request?

Tags: api, rest

Example: An API endpoint that accepts in a PET field the values "DOG" and "PET". If it receives an request with the payload value with "RABBIT",

```
{
  "animal": "RABBIT"
}
```

is a good practice return a 400 Bad Request (or even a 422 Unprocessable Entity) **with the list of the valid values in the message?**

Like "Invalid value for the animal field. Valid values: "DOG" and "CAT"? Or should i just return the http code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You SHOULD (in the RFC 2119 sense) return a representation that explains the situation.

> Except when responding to a HEAD request, the server SHOULD send a representation containing an explanation of the error situation, and whether it is a temporary or permanent condition.  These status codes are applicable to any request method.  User agents SHOULD display any included representation to the user. -- [RFC 7231](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7231#section-6.5)

Answer (score 1):

HTTP status code 400 is much general than 422. HTTP status code 422 feels like a much more appropriate response for situations where the data is understood, but is still not valid.

Even if you want to return 400 status code, it's correct. In any case, make sure that the error response in body explains what issue is.

```
HTTP/1.1 422 Unprocessable Entity

{
  "message": "Validation Failed",
  "errors": [
    {
      "field": "animal",
      "code": "RABBIT is not valid value. Value must be either PET or DOG"
    }
  ]
}
```